# Trigger from thread to main thread in XCB Event Loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, xcb

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get my main thread event loop which looks like:

```
const int MY_CUST_MSG(877);
xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    while (event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection)) {
        switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
            case MY_CUST_MSG:
                    // do something
                break;
            default:
                // Unknown event type, ignore it
                debug_log("Unknown event: ", event->response_type);
        }
        free(event);
    }
```

To react to a message from a secondary thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xcb_wait_for_event()` waits for an event to be received from the server. You'd have to send a message to yourself, through the server, but I would suggest an alternative approach:

1. Use `xcb_file_descriptor()` to get the underlying file descriptor for the X connection.
2. Set up an internal pipe that your application can use to send messages to itself, between thread.
3. Use `xcb_poll_for_event()` which is a non-blocking version of `xcb_wait_for_event()`, to implement a non-blocking check if there's an event that has been read, and if so, read it.
4. Do a non-blocking read on your internal pipe, to check for any internal message from another thread.
5. If neither step 3 or 4 produced a message, use `poll()` to wait for one or the other event.

You will also need to use `xcb_flush()` to flush any events manually, and `xcb_connection_has_error()` to check for a fatal connection error to the X server.

[See the tutorial](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Sam this is very interesting. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it went. If you have time may you please show the "message to yourself, through the server" method.

Comment: Is there any existing event I can use with `xcb_send_event`, I just need to send a string. Like possibly `XCB_EVENT_MASK_NO_EVENT`?

Comment: You can use the `ClientMessage` event. See [X11R7 protocol specification](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#events:ClientMessage) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I have no `window`, do I have to create a hidden message only window? Or is it possible without it?

Comment: Yes, this is what hidden message-only windows are for.

Comment: Thanks Sam! I was searching for message only window but I keep getting winapi solutions. May you point me in right direction. Excuse that please I'm very new to C++. First month. I'm having to dive into it because all my browser extensions were deperecated and I have to move to native messaging which requires me to make it stand alone then connect it to browser.

Comment: The actual proper term, in the context of the X protocol, is "input only window", and why are you wasting your time Googling, when I pointed you to the actual X11R7 protocol spec? xcb is merely a direct, one-for-one mapping between X11R7, and a C API. See the CreateWindow() message description.

Comment: Ah excuse that haha, I'll try driving into that spec now.

Comment: Hey Sam I'm thinking I'm making progress, does this approach (not syntax) in this code look correct - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/2b85723bf07306c87d345ab6be3abfbc

Comment: Hi @Sam I edited the question above so it reflects the solution you gave. I created another question about custom event to xcb server and back to just my app, may you please see - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40533318/1828637